# Can Varnish be deployed to front end mariadb/mysql server pool? Or is varnish helpful only when frontending HTTP servers?

Tags: mysql, varnish, mariadb

Can Varnish be used to front end a pool of mariadb/mysql servers? I see that it does not handle any non-http requests and gives 503 error.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the documentation? To just quote the first sentence: "Varnish Cache is a web application accelerator also known as a caching HTTP reverse proxy."

Answer (score 3):

Varnish is a HTTP Cache, so no it cannot act as a frontend for MariaDB/MySQL, unless you were trying to access them via HTTP.

I would recommend HAproxy as a frontend / load balancer solution for MariaDB/MySQL pool.

Answer (score 1):

No, Varnish is designed for http traffic and is not suitable for load-balancing mysql/mariadb